# What kind of topology is this (if it involves non-set operations)

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, semiring

Suppose we have $\cup, \cap$ defined as binary operations on "subsets" of some set $S$, where "subsets" can be something exotic like substrings of a string.  Suppose also that they satisfy analogous axioms for defining a topology on $S$.

Then I think the structure could be called a [semiring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring) as $S$ becomes the multiplicative ($\cap$) identity and $\varnothing$ becomes the additive ($\cup$) identity.  Suppose also that there exist a set difference operator that acts just like that between sets.

What can we say about the "topological side" of things if even possible.  Thanks.